# PHP PDO doesn't seem to be picking up first question mark

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to make a prepared query that can be used to select any number of users, and also filter them from a basic search functionality.

It looks like this:

```
$ALL_MEMBERS = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username LIKE '%?%' LIMIT ?, ?")
```

But PDO doesn't seem to be picking up that first '?' inbetween the '%'s. Any idea why?

(It gives me an error when I give 3 parameters, saying there's the wrong amount, whereas it doesn't when giving two parameters)

Comment: The user contributed notes in the PHP manual have [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#99698) to say

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely confusing PDO there with the quotes and percentages, it is looking for a ? mark. Write it as:

```
$database->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username LIKE ? LIMIT ?, ?");
```

And then have the first variable as:

```
$database->execute(array('%'.$A.'%',$B,$C));
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to do this:

```
$ALL_MEMBERS = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username LIKE ? LIMIT ?, ?")
```

PDO should already wrap strings for you.